# $C(X)$ is separable when $X$ is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact space and let $\Bbb U =\{(U,V); U,V \mbox{ are open subsets of }X \mbox{ and }\mathrm{cl} U \subset V\} $. for $u=(U,V)$ in $\Bbb U$ , let $F_u:X\to [0,1]$ be a continuous function such that $f_u=1$ on $\mathrm{cl} U$ and $f_u=0$ on $X \setminus V$. Show

a- the linear span of $\{f_u;u\in \Bbb U\}$ is dense in $C(X)$.

b- If X is a metric space, then $C(X)$ is separable.

c-If X is a $\sigma-$ compact metrizable locally compact space, then $C_0(X)$ is separable.

My attempt: a- put $M=\{f_u; u\in \Bbb U\}$. suppose $\mu \in M^{\perp}$. thus  for every open subset $U$, $\mu(U)=0$. Also  $||\mu||=|\mu|(X) =0$ which shows that $M^{\perp}=0$.

b- For every $n$, put $B_n=\{B(x,\frac{1}{n}) ; x\in X\}$. X is compact so there is a finite set $F_n\subset X$ such that  $\{B(x,\frac{1}{n}) ; x\in F_n\}$ is an open finite cover for X. put $F=\cup F_n$. I can show F is dense in X.

put $u_x= (B(x,\frac{1}{n}), B(x,\frac{1}{n-1}))$ for every $x\in F.$ I want to show $M=\{f_{u_x}, x\in F\}$ is dense in $C(X)$. But I can not.

c- $X=\cup X_n$ when every $X_n $ is compact.suppose $A_n$ is a countable dense set for  each $X_n$. put $A=\cup A_n$. clearly A is dense in X. Can I claim $C_0(X)=\cup C(X_n)$? 
so in this case $C_0(X)$ is separable.

I do not know my proof in part (a) is correct or not. Also I have problem in parts b,c.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your argument for part $a$ does not make sense unless you tell us what you mean by $\perp$.

Comment: @AdamHughes, your hint does not mean anything in this context, as the domain of the functions is not a subset of a field...

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that after rereading. I saw $[0,1]$ and my brain made that into $X$.

Comment: I mean $M^\perp=\{x^*\in X^* ; (m,x^*)=0 ~for ~ every ~ m\in M\}$

Comment: Please help me to find the answer.

Comment: a) I think you need to give more explanations on why $\mu(U)=0$ for every open $U$. You also did not seem to use compactness of $X$.

Comment: $\mu \in M^\perp $, so for every $f_u\in M^\perp $, $\int f_u d\mu=0$which shows that $\int \chi_U d\mu=0$.

Comment: a) and c) are correct

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.**

It is enough to show that one can approximate non-negatve functions by rational linear combinations of the bump functions$F_u$ you constructed, for every function is a difference of non-negative functions.

So let $f:X\to\mathbb R$ be continuous and non-negative, and suppose that $f$ is not identically zero. let $\mathcal G$ be the set of all finite linear combinations $g$ with rational coefficients of the functions $F_u$ such that $0\leq g\leq h$, and let $d=\inf\{\lVert f-g\rVert_\infty:g\in\mathcal G\}$. If we show that $d=0$, we will be done.

Can you do that? (One has to show that $\mathcal G$ is not empty to get things started, of course)

Comment: (-1) The question is widely applicable to a large audience. A detailed canonical answer is required to address all the concerns.

Comment: @Norbert, while that may be true, why should **I** be the one required to provide that canonical answer? I am pretty sure that that one of the silliest reasons for a downvote I've seen in a while...

Comment: If you post an answer to the question during the bounty you are confrming that you agree with requirements of this bounty.

Comment: That is simply an absurd claim. I could not care less for the bounty, and I could not agree less with any «requirements» whatsoever. The person offering the bounty is entirely free to judge that my answer does not satisfy him.

Comment: Firstly, hint **is not** a detailed canonical answer, which was **required**. There is nothing to argue here. Secondly I have a right to upvote and downvote and I use this "power". I even left a commment, so you don't guess why and who was that. Please don't bother me anymore.

Comment: In want universe was such an answer *required*?! You are free to up vote and downvote pretty much as you desire (up to the fact that some votes are automatically reverted in some circumstances, as when people downvote unrelated answers of the same user, for example) I am also free to think that the reason you gave for your downvote is simply absurd.